# Possible to create glass shatter animation in iOS SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit

I am a beginning programming creating a game on XCode primarily using Sprite Kit. I have been using a textbook "iOS Games by Tutorial" by Wenderlich, and it explains how to use the particle systems feature. The game I am making has a few custom made glass-textured objects that can fall (I am currently using a very crude 'explosion' as the shatter). I created a .MOV of a glass shatter animation but its size was 20MB which is several times the size of the rest of my game+images so I am hesitant to believe this is the correct method either. I was wondering if someone could give me advice as to how to make a decent-looking glass shatter animation using this or point me in the direction of a more advanced particle systems tutorial (or direct me to a better way of creating a glass shatter animation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with the SpriteKit particle system, and I came up with a not-as-crude glass-shatter pattern.

These variables are just samples, and can be modified and tailored to your specific taste (in the format of the particle editor fields, not code):

```
 Particle BirthRate: 1000  Maximum: 100
 Lifetime: 1  Range:0

 Position Range X: 100  Y:100
 Angle  Start: 90  Range: 90
 Speed  Start: 300  Range: 150
 Acceleration  X:0  Y:-1500

 Alpha: 1
 Scale: 1
 Rotation  Start: 0  Range: 350  Speed: 50

 Color:  Some sort of light cyan if you want a classic glass look
```

The most important factors seem to be the Y acceleration, and the very high birthrate and very (relatively) low particle maximum.  This results in a particle effect that looks like glass being shattered up slightly.